# Eclipse PDT - how do I force comprehensive file validation across a whole project

Tags: php, validation, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-oxygen

Eclipse PDT highlights problems in PHP files by display a warning chevron next to the file name in PHP Explorer.

...but for some reason I have files with problems that do not display. The only way I can find to force proper comprehensive re-validation of a file is to:

1. manually open the file
2. insert a blank
3. delete the blank I just inserted (ie. leaving the file in the same state as when opened)
4. save the file

On completion of the above steps, PDT correctly recognises that the file contains issues and displays a warning chevron next to the file in PHP Explorer pane.

While the above approach is ok for a single file, I am trying to get rid of all warning and error chevrons in my project and need some way of forcing full re-validation for all files in my project, without having to go into each file doing the above.

I have tried both:

1. refresh (F5); and
2. revalidate

and neither seem to do a comprehensive refresh.

Does anyone know how to force full comprehensive file re-validation across all files in a whole project such that PHP Explorer will display all issues contained in all files?